# how to sort GeoJson alphabetically by county(a key)?

Tags: json, python-3.x, flask, geojson, folium

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to organize my geojson data. I need json_counties['features']['properties'] to be sorted by 'name' which is the name of the counties.

input:

```
with open('california-counties.geojson') as f:
    json_counties = json.load(f);
json_counties['features']
```

output:

```
{'type': 'Feature',
 'properties': {'name': 'Alameda',
  'cartodb_id': 1,
  'created_at': '2015-07-04T21:04:58Z',
  'updated_at': '2015-07-04T21:04:58Z'},
 'geometry': {'type': 'MultiPolygon',
  'coordinates': [[[[-122.312934, 37.897333],
     [-122.28848, 37.897925],
     [-122.27418, 37.905025],
     [-122.263946, 37.903734],
     [-122.249477, 37.893086],
     [-122.248914, 37.886867],
     [-122.223878, 37.878326],
     [-122.216276, 37.868822],
     [-122.220389, 37.864427],
     [-122.204094, 37.851387],
     [-122.196101, 37.842005]....}},
{'type': 'Feature',
  'properties': {'name': 'Butte',
   'cartodb_id': 4,
   'created_at': '2015-07-04T21:04:58Z',
   'updated_at': '2015-07-04T21:04:58Z'},
  'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
   'coordinates': [[[-121.879249, 39.303608],...
```

Above is listed in a randomized order. For example, information on Alpine County should come after Butte County.

I got upto here,

```
sorted(json_counties['features']['properties'], key = lambda x:x['name'])
```

but I get an error

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: You haven't shown enough of your actual JSON, but it seems `'features'` is a list of dictionaries, so you probably need `sorted(json_counties["features"], key = lambda x:x["properties"]["name"])`

Comment: Thank you so much! you were right. I'm pegging myself for not catching that

Answer (score 0):

It seems `'features'` is a list of dictionaries.  If so you need:

```
sorted(json_counties["features"], key = lambda x:x["properties"]["name"])
```